# Why Windows changes a .text section of a 32-bit EXE file when it loaded into RAM?

Tags: windows, exe, 32bit-64bit, portable-executable, bin

I have a 32-bit windows executable file. A `.text` section of this file starts with these bytes:

```
68 50 a0 d0 00 e8 3c 68 84 00 59 c3 cc cc cc cc ..
```

Disassembled:

```
push 0xd0a050
call 0x846846
pop ecx
ret
int3
int3
int3
int3
..
```

But when I run the executable, the `.text` section in RAM becomes like this:

```
68 50 a0 1b 01 e8 3c 68 84 00 59 c3 cc cc cc cc ..
```

Disassembled:

```
push 0x11ba050
call 0x846846
pop ecx
ret
int3
int3
int3
int3
..
```

As you can see, the address at the `push` line is changed. How to explain it?

Note that if I build and run the 64-bit version of the executable, I get absolutely identical `.text` section in file and in RAM.

Software: Win10 x64, MSVC 2019 x86.

Comment: isn't that just normal relocation?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought about it. But I have never get such behavior for the 64bit version. Is it just a coincidence?

Comment: I believe 64-bit opens up RIP relative addressing which reduces the amount of relocation that may be required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Wow, that makes sense. Thank you. I think this might be an answer.